# 3m ergo mouse wheel scrolling 14.04

Tags: xorg, mouse, udev, mouse-scroll

I hope someone can help with this. Previously in Ubuntu 12 I was able to follow [these](http://roshansingh.in/blog/2012/12/14/getting-middle-button-of-3m-ergonomic-mouse-towork/) instructions to get my mouse wheel to work. In 14.04, the hal-* functions no longer work and I cannot seem to find a replacement. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288299/replacement-for-hal-get-property-and-hal-find-by-capability-in-udev) poster tried, but the reply there only works if you know the path on Ubuntu from what I understand.

I basically would like to add this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Middle Mouse Button Scrolling"
    MatchProduct "Areson USB Device"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
    Option "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
    Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
    Option "YAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```

Here /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ but I need to be able to fill in the "MatchProduct" field with the device name as installed.

Thank you very much for any help or suggestions you might have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get information about the USB devices udev has processed by entering:

```
lsusb -v
```

And then scroll through the (kind of voluminous) output to find the device you need to know about.

You can also find some information on all devices by looking in /var/log/udev as follows:

```
less /var/log/udev
```

Enter `/input/mouse` to find the first matching mouse processing. Type `n` to see subsequent mentions. The first `/` in `/input/mouse` tells the less program to find what follows: input/mouse.

Comment: Excellent that worked for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't mind applying the changes to all of your mice (or only have one) I'd suggest removing the two MATCH lines and replace them with:

```
MATCHISPOINTER 'true'
```

Be sure that the name of the file you create in that directory ends in .conf. I've forgotten that several times.

---

Alternatively

```
xinput list
```

will list the names by which the xserver knows all devices. This particular information is from ManuelSchneid3r at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72732.